# Unable to create a conda environment from a text file

Tags: conda, miniconda

I've been trying to create a conda environment from a text file using this command

```
conda env create --name tf2_gpu --file /Dedicated/jmichaelson-wdata/ebahl/mlab/thesis/cell_activity/neuronal-activity-score/conda/tf2_gpu_pkgs.txt
```

and it keeps giving me this error

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - conda-forge/linux-64::gxx_impl_linux-64==7.5.0=hdf63c60_6
  - conda-forge/linux-64::gcc_impl_linux-64==7.5.0=hd420e75_6
  - @explicit
  - conda-forge/linux-64::gfortran_impl_linux-64==7.5.0=hdf63c60_6
```

I thought it could be because I have another version of miniconda (4.10.3) than the version that this environment text file is from (4.8.0). So, I reinstalled miniconda with v 4.8.0 and same python used for that env text file (3.7.8). However, I still get the same error when trying to create this new environment.

Any thought what could be the issue here?

Update:
I searched for one of the packages (gfortran_impl_linux-64) using the command `conda search gfortran_impl_linux-64=7.5.0[build=hdf63c60_6]`, and couldn't find it.
So I tried looking for the package without specifying the build,  `conda search gfortran_impl_linux-64`, and got this

```
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
gfortran_impl_linux-64           5.4.0      hdf63c60_3  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.2.0      hb3c8cce_2  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.2.0      hdf63c60_3  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.3.0      hdf63c60_0  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.3.0      hdf63c60_1  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.3.0      hdf63c60_2  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.3.0      hdf63c60_3  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.3.0      hdf63c60_4  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.3.0      hdf63c60_5  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_14  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_15  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_16  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h56cb351_18  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h56cb351_19  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_10  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_11  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_12  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_13  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     ha8c8e06_17  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     hfca37b7_17  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.4.0     h5ed45b9_17  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.4.0     h603fa6f_17  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.4.0     h863adf9_14  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.4.0     h863adf9_15  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.4.0     h863adf9_16  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.4.0     hd6a5828_18  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.4.0     hd6a5828_19  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.5.0     h7faea26_10  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.5.0     h7faea26_11  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.5.0      h7faea26_8  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           8.5.0      h7faea26_9  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     h2bb4189_17  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     h5abd6ed_17  pkgs/main           
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     h64c220c_11  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     h64c220c_12  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     h64c220c_13  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     hc4a2995_18  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     hc4a2995_19  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     hde52e87_14  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     hde52e87_15  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.3.0     hde52e87_16  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0     h0003116_10  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0     h0003116_11  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0      h0003116_3  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0      h0003116_4  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0      h0003116_5  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0      h0003116_6  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0      h0003116_7  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0      h0003116_8  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           9.4.0      h0003116_9  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0     h73f4979_10  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0     h73f4979_11  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0      h73f4979_3  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0      h73f4979_4  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0      h73f4979_5  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0      h73f4979_6  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0      h73f4979_7  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0      h73f4979_8  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          10.3.0      h73f4979_9  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.1.0      hc0c744c_3  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.1.0      hc0c744c_4  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.1.0      hc0c744c_5  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.1.0      hc0c744c_6  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.1.0      hc0c744c_7  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.1.0      hc0c744c_8  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.2.0     h7a446d4_10  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.2.0     h7a446d4_11  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.2.0      h7a446d4_8  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64          11.2.0      h7a446d4_9  conda-forge
```

So, it could find the package but not the specified build it's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I exported the environment file again without adding builds, and it worked.
just added `--no-builds` to the export command.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior here is due to packages being marked as `broken`. The Conda or Miniconda versions do not affect this.

### Anaconda Cloud excludes packages labelled "`broken`"

Sometimes problems are discovered with specific builds of a package that can merit effective removal from search. [Conda Forge documents](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/updating_pkgs.html#removing-broken-packages) how maintainers can trigger such a removal, and appears to be accomplished by adding the `broken` label to a package. Unfortunately, I can't find any specific Anaconda Cloud documentation on how this works, but `broken` is part of [the default set of labels](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/admin-guide/install/config/config-reference/?highlight=labels#standard-labels) that an Anaconda repository expects.

In this specific case, one can see on the Anaconda Cloud website that the specific build is still available, but has been labelled `broken`:

[image: anaconda cloud file tab for gfortran_impl_linux-64=7.5.0]

As shown by OP, using default `conda search` settings does not report these:

**Default search results**

```bash
$ mamba search -q conda-forge::gfortran_impl_linux-64=7.5.0
Loading channels: ...working... done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_14  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_15  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_16  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h56cb351_18  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h56cb351_19  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_10  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_11  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_12  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_13  conda-forge         
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     hfca37b7_17  conda-forge
```

However, the MatchSpec grammar is expressive enough to search under specific labels:

**Searching the `broken` label**

```bash
$ mamba search -q conda-forge/label/broken::gfortran_impl_linux-64=7.5.0
Loading channels: ...working... done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      h64c220c_7  conda-forge/label/broken
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      h64c220c_8  conda-forge/label/broken
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      h64c220c_9  conda-forge/label/broken
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      hdf63c60_6  conda-forge/label/broken
```

or, since the `main` label is still retained on packages marked as `broken`, one could ignore the `broken` label by specifying to search all `main` packages:

**Search all `main` packages**

```bash
$ mamba search -q conda-forge/label/main::gfortran_impl_linux-64=7.5.0
Loading channels: ...working... done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_14  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_15  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h1104b78_16  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h56cb351_18  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h56cb351_19  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_10  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_11  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_12  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     h64c220c_13  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      h64c220c_7  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      h64c220c_8  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      h64c220c_9  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0      hdf63c60_6  conda-forge/label/main
gfortran_impl_linux-64           7.5.0     hfca37b7_17  conda-forge/label/main
```

### Recommended Workaround

[As found by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584761/570918), a simple workaround is to remove the build part of the string (`=hdf63c60_6`) in the environment/package specification file. This enables Conda to substitute other builds that are not labelled as `broken`.

This can be done for all packages by including the `--no-builds` flag.

### Workaround: Exact Environment Recreation

> **⚠️ Warning:** The following approach enables packages labelled as `broken` to be installed! This is advanced usage that should only be performed by users who understand the consequences.

This last search result suggests that one can override the `broken` label behavior by including the channel `conda-forge/label/main` during installation or in a YAML file. There may be circumstances where this is desirable, such as needing to exactly recreate an environment for reproducing scientific results.

I would only recommend this for recreating an environment from a YAML or other environment serialization that *includes build specifications*, otherwise one might risk including `broken` packages in more than just the specific case. In practice, I would likely use a `flexible` channel priority, and keep the `main` label at lower priority. For example,

```bash
CONDA_CHANNEL_PRIORITY=flexible conda env create -n foo -c conda-forge -c conda-forge/label/main -f env.yaml
```

This helps ensure that non-broken packages still take priority if an equivalent case is encountered.